GrandNode 2.0 Caching Issue: Changes in Admin Not Reflecting on Frontend Immediately
I'm working with GrandNode 2.0.0 for an e-commerce project. The setup consists of two separate projects:
Grand.Web (frontend), running on one port.
Grand.Admin (admin backend), running on a different port.
The issue is that when I perform actions such as editing, deleting, or inserting entities (e.g., products or categories) in Grand.Admin, the changes do not immediately reflect on the Grand.Web frontend.
I have implemented caching for some custom code in a plugin. However, even when modifying entities using this plugin, I encounter the same issue where the frontend does not update right away.
Question:
How can I ensure that changes made in Grand.Admin immediately reflect on the Grand.Web frontend? Are there best practices or recommended solutions for managing caching and invalidation across separate applications in GrandNode?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Invalidating cache in my custom code.
Ensuring proper event publishing/subscribing mechanisms.
It seems like the cache is not being cleared or synchronized between the two applications.
